# bash script counting consecutive packet loss

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ping

I want to ping a `destination_ip` and redirect the count of consecutive packet loss to a `ping_result.txt` file.
Suppose that ping result is like the following:

```
reply from destination_ip
request timed out
request timed out
reply from destination_ip
request timed out
request timed out
request timed out
request timed out
reply from destination_ip
```

the output should be like the following:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
3
4
0
```

Comment: In future, it'd be nice to see the code you have attempted, rather than just getting someone to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In awk:

```
... | awk '/reply/{count = 0} {print count++}' > ping_result.txt
```

Essentially:

- Reset `count` if reply was received.
- Print `count` and increment it.

Comment: Thank you muru for beautiful advise and use of awk

Answer (score 2):

Not even close to as beautiful as [muru's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42409634/6468580) answer, but for someone who's not quite as weathered using awk this is what I would do:

This is provided you have the counting consecutive packet loss output saved in a file -- *output.txt*.

```
COUNT=0
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "reply"* ]]
        then ((COUNT=0))  
    else ((COUNT++)) 
    fi
    echo $COUNT
done < output.txt > ping_result.txt
```

So it loops through the file, finding any line which begins with reply and setting that count to 0 otherwise incrementing.

I've just read through [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). So it's probably not the best idea.

Comment: Thank you Fubar.
Actually I was expecting such programming.
However Muru's advice was a great shortcut ;)